# how to access TextBox inside ListBox itemsSource which is Datatemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

I have a `ListBox` and its `ItemsSource` is linked with a `ComboBox` `SelectedItem`. Its template is associated with a `DataTemplate`. Everything is fine but how to access each `TextBox` inside `ListBoxItems`. I have 5 labels and 2 `TextBoxes` inside each `ListItem`. I want to access each and every `TextBox` and labels inside `ListBoxItem`. I need some idea how to access each `TextBox` inside each Item. For example, there is "wbprofileDesc" `TextBox` in first `ListBoxItem`. So I need to access this `TextBox` and write some functionality to it like keypress event. It need to work for each and every `TextBox` inside all the `ListBoxItems` individually. Assume there are 5 `ListBoxItems`. Also I need to fetch other controls also like wbselect(`ComboBox`), wbdepth, wbwidthvalue and etc. I am using MVVM model for this.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:wbItemViewModel x:Key="wbItem"/>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="wbObjectsDataTemplate">
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Height="Auto" Width="642" Margin="0,0,0,-14">
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="697"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="54" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="49*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="91*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="309*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="306*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="5"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="{Binding WBName_lbl}" Margin="0,3,0,5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/> 

        <ComboBox x:Name="wbselect" Margin="5,0,10,1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0">
          <ComboBoxItem x:Name="wbstraight" IsSelected="True" Content="straight"/>
          <ComboBoxItem x:Name="wbtapered" Content="tapered"/>
        </ComboBox>

        <!--KeyDown="{Binding Path=profileDesc}"-->
        <!-- KeyDown="profileDesc_KeyDown" -->
        <TextBox x:Name="wbprofileDesc" Margin="18,0,20,1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" GotFocus="wbprofileDesc_GotFocus"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="wbdepth" Text="{Binding ElementName=wbwidthvalue, Path=Content, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,73,1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label x:Name="wbwidthvalue" Margin="10,0,190,5" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="8" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label x:Name="wbthicknessvalue" Margin="118,0,82,5" FontSize="8" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="wblengthvalue" Margin="208,0,0,5" FontSize="8" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="wbnexwidthvalue" Margin="10,0,178,5" FontSize="8" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <Label x:Name="wbdepthvalue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="8" Margin="132,0,31,5"/>
        <!--<Label x:Name="totalvalue" Margin="30,10,24,16" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"/>-->
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="wbListDataTemplate"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding wbVisibleItems}"           
         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource wbObjectsDataTemplate}"
         DataContext="{DynamicResource wbItem}"
         Background="{x:Null}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding wbSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         Canvas.Top="51" Height="222" Width="686"/>
```

Comment: For what reason? If you would actually be "using MVVM", there would be no need to access elements in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: i am using Combobox and according to it's selected value the ListItems need to change. So using MVVM.

Comment: The ItemsControl in your DataTemplate makes no sense. It only has a single item, i.e. the Grid. That's not how ItemsControl is supposed to be used.

Comment: I created DataTemplate in window.resources and linked with the ListBox ItemTemplate. There's no wrong with the design. I am getting the design how I need. I need some idea how to access each textbox inside each Itemtemplate. I need to perform some operations to them.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. A single Grid inside an ItemsControl makes no sense. Read this: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: What are you intending to do with the controls that you want to access?

Comment: @mm8 I edited the question for your understanding. I need some idea pls.

Comment: Do you want to access the wbprofileDesc TextBox from within the GotFocus event handler or what is your issue?

Comment: @Clemens In your link i can see "Adding More to the DataTemplate". There it was designed inside Grid like my design. Should i remove Grid and paste it inside ListBox? Anyhow I removed ItemsControl and updated now.

Comment: @mm8 yes exactly mm8. I am not able to access wbprofileDesc TextBox for each ListBoxItem. Also I need to access the other textboxes text and labels contents inside each ListBoxItem. Calling them is little difficult it seems.

Comment: Then you are obviously *not* have a clue about what the MVVM pattern is all about. You certainly don't follow it.

Comment: @mm8 the thing is, i am using ComboBox and according to it's selected value the ListBoxItems Count is changing. I am using InotifyPropertyChanged for  ComboBox and ViewModel linked to it. it was working fine. Shouldn't I use MVVM for this?

Comment: You should bind to properties of the object to which the DataTemplate is applied.

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to accomplish first. Mentioning MVVM and "accessing controls" in the same sentence doesn't make much sense. Please edit your question.

Comment: @mm8 I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of you could find the controls in the `DataTemplate` inside the event handler:

```
private void wbprofileDesc_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox wbprofileDesc = sender as TextBox;
    Grid parentGrid = wbprofileDesc.Parent as Grid;

    ComboBox wbselect = parentGrid.Children.OfType<ComboBox>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "wbselect");
    Label wbwidthvalue = parentGrid.Children.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "wbwidthvalue");
}
```

Comment: Can this same code work for a button? where all the items are processed at a time.